# Input fields not responding

Tags: html, css

For some reason my input field and my submit button are not working. My source and the result in [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VPnSm/2/)

What am I doing wrong? What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, `z-index: -10` is putting #content-box behind the entire body. Removing that line allows text to be inputted.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` property works only on positioned elements. That means - any `position` except `static`. In your example (http://jsfiddle.net/VPnSm/4) `#triage` didn't have any position, but had a `z-index` which wasn't working.

What I did to your fiddle is this:

- Added `position: relative` to `#triage`
- Changed `z-index` property of `#content-box` to 0 (do you really need it to be that negative?)
- Added `position: relative;` and `z-index` properties to the `input` elements in `#content-box`

Which resulted in this fiddle, where `input` elements work :)

http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/VPnSm/6/